# Multiple Assigned To Field on Task Lists

Tags: email, task-list

I have two people/group lookup fields on my task list. One field is the original 'Assigned to' and sends out an email when ownership is assigned. I would like both of my "Assigned to" fields to send emails to people/groups added to the field. Is it possible?

Comment: My mistake, I am actually using a issues list, not a task list.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Assigned To field to allow multiple values or use a workflow to send an email to the person in your other column.

Answer (score 0):

I came across same requiremnets, worth reading this 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/7e9eab35-3cc0-47b1-8481-64b5fbf4be1f/more-than-1-assigned-to-field-in-task-list?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy

I am planning to create SPD workflow for this.